# foreign non-C library

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-dune

I want to use a library built as a `.a` file in my dune project (exposing some needed functions...), but [the dune documentation](https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/stable/foreign-code.html) specifies only how to use foreign C code.

How can one use a non-C built library with dune?

What I am currently trying to do (I can't see how to apply the process of the documentation with a non-C generated program):

Part of my `dune` file:

```
(foreign_archives ../bin_jasmin/TESTS)
```

My main program:

```ml
module ForeignFuncs = struct
  open Ctypes
  open Foreign

  let test_ADCX =
    foreign "test_ADCX"
      (ocaml_bytes @-> ocaml_bytes @-> uint64_t @-> uint64_t @-> uint8_t
     @-> returning void)
end
```

p.s.: I already used this library with Ctypes, compiling with ocamlopt and it worked just fine. For those curious, this is about using [Jasmin](https://github.com/jasmin-lang/jasmin)

Comment: Can you link it with `ld` or similar?

Comment: @RawleyFowler I will try that (ld after dune compiles it right ?), but even if this works, it doesn't solve the initial problem (link non-C foreigns library with dune)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using dune, so you should be able to have a link_flags field in your `executable` stanza.  Something like

```lisp
 (link_flags (-ccopt -Lpath/to/archive -cclib -lmy-library))
```

You still need a rule to generate the archive of course.  My dune foo is not great so what I have done in the past is to use a Makefile (which I am more familiar with) to build the archive and have the Makefile call up dune when building the OCaml executable, which has the archive as a dependency.  Note that if using a relative path to the archive, the path in the dune file is relative (by default) to the _build/default directory.  Your non-C built library may in turn require its own support library to be linked in and it would have to be prepared using C linkage and calling conventions.